# Django, multiple abstract base class having same fields

Tags: django, model

Abstract class Abs1 and Abs2 has the field `field_1` with same name.
Is it fine to inherit from both of them?

```
class Abs1(model):
  field_1 = IntegerField()
  class Meta:
     abstract=True

class Abs2(model):
  field_1 = IntegerField()
  class Meta:
     abstract=True

class Concreate(Model, Abs1, Abs2):
  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Python will override one of the `field_1` fields determined by MRO (https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

If your end goal is to just end up with one `field_1` then this is fine, as python will just select one and use that.

Comment: I don't think this is how it works in django. You'll get an error when checking the models.

Comment: My mistake, it does work this way as long as you don't use a class and its subclass at the same time. (https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24542)